# Positive lookback regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like so:

```
String sample = "name:Bob | time:2:20";
```

I am practicing regex and trying to use the following code in attempt to remove the “:” from 2:20

```
sample = sample.replace("(?<=0-9):","");
```

Where is the regex incorrect as it doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: `0-9` matches the exact string `"0-9"`. I guess you wanted `[0-9]`, which matches any (single character) digit

Comment: @C-Otto probably not, the regex is valid. (I assume the `“”` quotes are a copy-paste problem, maybe from using Word with autocorrect in a French locale)

Comment: @C-Otto I got no error message but the replace just didn’t work and  yes I’m looking to remove any “:” that comes after a number

Comment: Also `replace` doesn't support regex. Use `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll`

Comment: `sample = sample.replaceFirst("(?<=[0-9]):", "");` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9]):", "");
```

But could be made more efficient by using capturing groups instead of lookbehinds :

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("([0-9]):", "$1");
```

Where `[0-9]` is a `[character class]` composed of the range of characters from `0` to `9`, which is grouped inside a `(capturing group)` to which we make an index-based `$reference` in the replacement pattern : instead of replacing the `:` by the empty string, we replace the digit and following colon by the digit alone.

Comment: I will Mark as correct once I can. Lovely thank you. I find the syntax for regex quite confusing

Comment: It may be confusing, but its totally worth to learn RegEx since its pretty powerful.

Comment: @alwaysStuck123 I've added an explanation, hope it helps ! If you're still confused by some point please tell me and I'll try to make it clear :) Better follow a complete tutorial or course if you haven't already anyway, there's a lot of things to learn about regex.